# Can MulDiv be less efficient than storing known values and doing the math in other code

Tags: windows, delphi, optimization, math, delphi-2007

I am using Delphi 2007 and working on some presentation software. The current module I am working on is the transition filter for video. The transition code I am using (TPicShow's PSEffects unit) requires and X and a Y value based on the dimensions of the frame and the progress of the transition. Here is the code

```
Type
TPercent = 0..100;
var
ATo  : TBitmap; //
Prog : Integer; //Progress of the transition

      if ATo.Width >= ATo.Height then
    begin
      X := MulDiv(ATo.Width, Prog, High(TPercent));
      Y := MulDiv(X, ATo.Height, ATo.Width);
    end
  else
    begin
      Y := MulDiv(ATo.Height, Prog, High(TPercent));
      X := MulDiv(Y, ATo.Width, ATo.Height);
    end;
```

I am trying to optimize this and saw that I could save the calculations that would be constant (until the dimensions of ATo change) and remove 2 division calculations each frame.

So it would be something like

```
{All of these are calculated when the dimensions of ATo Change}
WDP : real; // width divided by High(TPercent)
HDW : real; // Height divided by width
HDP : real; // Height divided by High(TPercent)
WDH : real; // Width divided by Height

  if ATo.Width >= ATo.Height then
    begin
      X := Trunc(WDP * Prog);
      Y := Trunc(HDW * X);
    end
  else
    begin
      Y := Trunc(HDP * Prog);
      X := Trunc(WDH * Y);
    end;
```

It sounds good but not having the actual code of MulDiv I cant be sure. If it simply does (very simplified)

```
MulDiv(a,b,c : Integer)
begin
  Round((A*B)/C);
end
```

Then I know my change will be more efficient, however if MulDiv does anything very cool with optimizing the function (Which I'd thing it might) then I'm not sure if my change would net me anything.

Would my change be more efficient?

EDIT: I have not yet implemented this, I'm just entertaining the notion.

Comment: Please note that the value of `Y` doesn't actually depend on `X`. You calculate `Y` as `MulDiv(X, ATo.Height, ATo.Width)`, but you could calculate it more directly as `MulDiv(ATo.Height, Prog, 100)`. Once you do that, you should see that the calculations of `X` and `Y` are *identical* regardless of whether the width is greater than the height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be very surprised if calls to MulDiv, which is implemented using integer operations, were inefficient and the source of your performance problems. Have you timed your program? Have you used a profiler to identify the hot spots in your app?

Personally I think it is unlikely that a switch from integer to double precision floating point operations is likely to yield performance improvements.

In any case, my guess would be that you have other code which you call after the code you have shown, which uses `X` and `Y` and which consumes orders of magnitude more CPU than this little snippet. You presumably don't calculate `X` and `Y` and then discard them: what do you do with them?

**EDIT**: The Wine implementation of MulDiv is presumably very close to the Windows one, and the guts of that is so:

```
if ( ( (nMultiplicand <  0) && (nMultiplier <  0) ) ||
     ( (nMultiplicand >= 0) && (nMultiplier >= 0) ) )
  ret = (((LONGLONG)nMultiplicand * nMultiplier) + (nDivisor/2)) / nDivisor;
else
  ret = (((LONGLONG)nMultiplicand * nMultiplier) - (nDivisor/2)) / nDivisor;
```

Comment: I don't believe this situation to be the sole source of my performance issues but I was curious to see if I could improve this little snippet. As for the X and Y, I do nothing with them other than pass them into functions in the PSeffect unit belonging to TPicShow made by Kambiz Khojasteh. I haven't looked into his code too much yet as I wanted to optimize everything in my own code first. But at a cursory glance it does seem that at least a handful of transition function while taking in X and Y don't use them, so there is room for improvement there.

Comment: @Tim My main point is that improving this little snippet of code won't help if it is not a bottleneck. If the code in TPicShow is doing anything significant then making this snippet optimal will not save you any time. Before you optimise you *need* to understand what is slow. If you optimise the wrong thing then you actually make things worse because, very commonly, heavily optimised code is hard to understand and then becomes a maintenance problem. Typically the end result of premature optimisation is a program that is no faster than before, and no longer works correctly!

Comment: +1 for the last comment David. That makes a lot of sense to me having thought about it a minute and reading some code optimization material.

Answer (score 3):

You can't find the actual code of [MulDiv](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383718%28VS.85%29.aspx) because it's a WinAPI function. I'd suspect, though, that because it's used heavily in the WinAPI itself, it's probably some pretty well optimized assembler code, rather than just a couple of function calls.

As far as whether your change would be more efficient, the only way to determine that is to profile the code both ways and see which is faster. Search here for "Delphi profiler" for some suggestions (if you're using Delphi XE, you can use the included AQTime).

BTW, when you're talking about things like optimization and so forth, it's frequently very useful to indicate which Delphi version you're actually using, as changes in the compiler can make a difference in the answers.

Comment: Thank you, I had mentioned which version of Delphi I was using in the first paragraph but I added it to the tags now too.

Comment: Some code that might be "faster" when you think without including virtual memory into the equation merely becomes resource bound, instead of purely CPU bound.  Thus Ken's wise statement that until you have profiler data to support your ideas, your app is probably slower, and merely more bloated (uses more RAM).

Answer (score 1):

As other people have stated, you should be looking to a profiler to identify hotspots.

Once you have identified them, finding something faster than your current code, in your case, in a multimedia application, might require that you learn about SIMD machine language instructions, and might require that you write replacement hand-optimized assember code, to obtain any faster results.

Writing something yourself in Pascal, using floating point types, is VERY unlikely to result in any performance improvements.  Caching intermediate results will probably result in exponential increases in memory usage, with only a moderate improvement in speed, that might actually slow you down on systems where vm paging (thrashing) is likely to occur.